# Does Docker's EXPOSE not breach the supposed sandboxing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, docker, amazon-ec2

I am missing a piece of the puzzle. Running a docker image (say on a Linux EC2 instance) through

```
> sudo docker run -p 80:xyzw webapp_image:version
```

makes the *container* reachable at port 80, which means (via `EXPOSE xyzw` in the `Dockerfile`) that the container has affected its host.

Does that not contradict the premise of Docker containers? The idea, just like virtualization, appeared to be that a container runs in a sandbox and is unable to affect its host. Yet here it is able to expose itself on the host's port. Does the fact that this is doable not breach the supposed isolation? Should the mapping not be done on the host's command line, not from within the container? Suppose you have two containers on the same host, and both try to expose through the same port, then, potentially, some race would occur to see who'll get there first. Or is the idea that sandboxing is indeed observed, except that here the mapping occurs on the command line of the host?

Comment: What’s not working?  It seems like you’ve described all of the key parts.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure myself anymore. Let me reword the question.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I route port 80 of the EC2 instance to port 80 of the
>   container?

If I understood the context, you can do this by running below command -
`$ sudo docker run -p 80:80 webapp_image:version`

This routes port 80 of the host machine to port 80 of the container.

After this you need to open port 80 in security group of the EC2 instance & if it still deosn't work, follow the checkpoints -
1.  Firewalls on the host machine like iptables, selinux etc.
2.  Validate EC2 instance security groups in AWS.
3. Validate NACL rules for subnets in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this line `EXPOSE 80` in your Docker file? If yes then run `docker run -p 80:80 webapp_image:version`. The -p 80:80 option maps the exposed port 80 on the container to port 80 on the host machine(EC2).

Comment: Whether you EXPOSE something or not in the Dockerfile makes absolutely no difference here.